# Predict zero-inflated negative binomial to raster with raster::predict

Tags: r-raster

I am trying to predict a ZINB model to a raster. My code looks like this:

```
m1 <- pscl::zeroinfl(Herbround ~ LandcoverCode | LandcoverCode, data = data, dist = 'negbin')

r <- raster("data\\final.tif") # read in raster
names(r) <- "LandcoverCode" # match terminology in the model

#predict model to raster
predict(r, m1)

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contrasts.arg[[nn]]) : 
  contrasts apply only to factors
In addition: Warning message:
In model.frame.default(delete.response(object$terms$full), newdata,  :
  variable 'LandcoverCode' is not a factor
```

I then get the error above. If I use an lm or glm model it works without issues and I know that my LandcoverCode is in fact a factor with multiple levels (6 to be exact). I have tried adding in:

```
predict(r, m1, type = "count")
```

But that doesn't work either. Any help with predicting a ZINB model to a raster would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. That is, create a small dataset in R (or perhaps using files that ship with R, see `?raster::predict`)that reproduces the problem  Without that it is very difficult to understand what the problem is and how to solve it.